# Rails Routing: Set specific controller action to a different path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am looking to set the `show` action for a controller to a specific path (a path without the controller prefix). I know this can be done by controller by doing this

```
resources :items, path: ''
```

But is there a way to do this on only one specific action within the controller?

My end goal is to be able to say `www.example.com/my-item-name` and take the user to the item without changing the URL. I tried using a catchall route but redirecting adds the prefix back which I do not want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify which controller and action respond to a certain route in your `routes.rb` file, like this:

```
get 'something', to: 'controller_name#action_name'
```

See [Rails Routing Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes).

Answer (score 1):

You can define single routes manually with the `match`, `get`,`post`, `put`, macros:

```
get :bar, to: 'foos#bar'
get :bar, controller: 'foos' # works the same as above
post :bar, to: 'foos#bar'
```

You can also use `scope` if you want to route multiple routes to the same controller more elegantly:

```
scope controller: 'foos' do
  get :bar
  get :baz
end
```